# Incorrect flexbox items positioning in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I have a horizontal row with two 50%/50% containers. One of them is flexbox-container, that contains two elements with different position values:

[image: Normal view]

Code looks like that (don't pay attention on cyrillic text):

```
<div class="row spec-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 spec-name">
        <img src="images/specs/it-spec.jpg" alt="IT-специалист">
        <h4 class="display-5">IT-специалист</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 spec-desc">
        <p>IT-специалист – широкое понятие, объединяющее в себе представителей многих профессий, работающих в области информационных технологий.
            Это всевозможные программисты, разработчики, администраторы сетей и баз, модераторы, специалисты по робототехнике, по информационной безопасности, web-дизайнеры и даже 3D-аниматоры.
            При этом, с проникновением информационных технологий во всё новые сферы деятельности, появляются новые профессии для IT-специалистов.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And styles:

```
.spec-row .spec-name {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle; }
.spec-row .spec-name img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  filter: blur(5px) grayscale(100%);
  transition: filter 0.3s ease; }
.spec-row .spec-name h4 {
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 1rem 5%;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.3s ease; }
```

(I past here only .spec-name styles cause .spec-desc has no troubles)

---

### THE PROBLEM

When I open this page in Firefox, I see this:

[image: Breaked view]

And I have no ideas how to fix it, cause I see no problems in other webkit-based browsers (and in Edge too).

So, I have only one question - how to fix it?